# cramming/embedding integers into strings in C++

Tags: c++, string, casting, byte, stringstream

i have some data that has to match a certain packet protocol.  i'm getting said data as a std::string.

i need to take some integer values and put them in the string in certain locations.  i don't want to convert the integer to string values; i want to copy the actual byte values in.

so for example, if my string is "abcdefg", and i have a 2 byte short with the value of 25 that i want to put into the 1st position, i don't want "a25defg".  i want "a" + 0x00 + 0x19 + "defg" (forgive me for that.  it was the best way i could think to illustrate what i want).

is there a slick way to do this using regular C++ strings?  boost isn't a possibility for me here due to system req's.

from what i see, stringstream may help, but all of the examples i see are converting the number/short/integer into the ascii version of it, and that's not what i want.

i can easily do this with char arrays, but i was wondering if i can do it with strings.

thanks.

Comment: There are many things that affect the question. The first of which is whether the protocol uses `std::string` because it is a text based protocol or whether `std::string` is an abuse of `std::vector<unsigned char>`, will the protocol handle NUL characters in the string? Is the size of the string fixed in the protocol?

Comment: yes, let's us assume that.  endianness gets checked before this code ever gets hit.

Comment: good questions.  the string is a fixed size, as the protocol is defined.  and yes, the protocol does need null characters and can handle them, which is one of the reasons for using std::string.  i know how to do this using char arrays.  i'm just really curious on how it can be done with std::string.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Yes, a std::string can contain `\0` characters. That is one of the many advantages of std::strings over C-type strings!

Comment: @MrLister: I know that `std::string` can hold NUL characters, the question was whether the *protocol* can handle the NUL (or at any point is processed as a C string --I have seen that quite a few times)

Comment: gah! my question got a -1?  what did i do wrong?

Comment: protocol uses lots of 0x00 for placeholders in spare locations.  0x00 is legal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say it's easy to do with char arrays, but it's just as easy with std::strings!

```
std::string str = "abcdef";
short val = 25;
str[1] = val>>8;
str[2] = val&255;
```

That works the way you want. If the protocol is big-endian.

**Edit:**
This works only if you want to replace existing chars in the string. To create a new string from scratch, or add a value at the end, see Dani's answer.

Comment: this is what i was looking for.  i really need to learn my bitwise operators a little better.  now let me ask you a second question. how can i append on a short in the same manner?  would i need to append 2 values and then use your same method, or is there a better way?  thanks a lot btw.

Comment: Well, you shouldn't use [ ] indexing to append characters (i.e. write after the current end of the string), so you could, for instance, append `"xx"` first and then change the contents of the appended bytes. But then it becomes a less simple and elegant method...

Comment: @MrLister: yes, I hadn't seen that one yet. :/

Answer (score 2):

Its not recommended, but you can just reinterpret it:

```
short something = 25;
string something_string(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&something),
                        sizeof(something));
// something_string == 19 00
```

You need to take care of endianess though, (like `hton`)

Comment: and `str.append(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(val), sizeof(val));` and also `str.replace(1, 2, reinterpret_cast<const char*>(val), sizeof(val));` to save you minuscule amounts of time.

Answer (score 0):

```
template<size_t N>
void cram_helper( unsigned long long value, char* const dst )
{
    char* p = dst + N;
    while (p > dst) { *--p = value & 0xFF; value >>= 8; }
}

template<typename T>
void cram( T t, char* dst )
{
    cram_helper<sizeof(T)>(t, dst);
}

char buffer[] = { "abcdefg" };
short s = 25;
cram(s, buffer+1);

string buffer1 = "abcdefg";
cram(s, &buffer[1]);
```

---

```
template<size_t N, typename Container>
void cram_helper( unsigned long long value, Container& dst, int initial_index )
{
    char index = initial_index + N;
    while (index > initial_index) { dst[--index] = value & 0xFF; value >>= 8; }
}

template<typename T, typename Container>
void cram( T t, Container& dst, size_t initial_index = 0 )
{
    cram_helper<sizeof(T)>(t, dst, initial_index);
}

std::string buffer2 = "abcdefg";
short s = 25;
cram(s, buffer2, 1);
```

Comment: can this be done without using char* or char arrays?  using straight access to a std::string or the std::string library?